# Partial Word Search VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm using the following snippet of code in the `TextChanged` routine of a textbox to search a datagridview and filter based on the results. This only works if the searched for item is in the same order as the text typed. For example, to search for Green Apple I have to type Green Apple, where as I would just like to type Apple. Is there a way of doing a mid word search?

```
 source1.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'", "Description", SearchBx.Text)
```

Query code to populate datagrid

```
         toLoad = cbDisplay.Text & ".csv"

        Dim odf As String = "C:\Dropbox\Queries\Cats\" & toLoad


        Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & Path.GetDirectoryName(odf) & """;Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited"";"


        Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
        objConn.Open()
        Dim objCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [PID], [Tertiary Category], ([Brand] + ' ' + [Description]) as Description, [Pack Description] FROM " & odf, objConn)
        Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter

        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect
        Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet


        objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "test")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView

        objConn.Close()

        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "PID"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Tertiary"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Description"
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Pack Size"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic

        Dim columnwidth1 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(0)
        columnwidth1.Width = 94
        Dim columnwidth2 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(1)
        columnwidth2.Width = 125
        Dim columnwidth3 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(2)
        columnwidth3.Width = 240
        Dim columnwidth4 As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(3)
        columnwidth4.Width = 94

        source1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Comment: Your current filter string, `"{0} LIKE '{1}%'"` is equivalent to a `StartsWith` search. To find any entry that `Contains` just modify your filter string to this: `"{0} LIKE '%{1}%'"`

Comment: Excellent, works like a treat. Thanks